# Are there issues when creating a branch with the name of an old re-named branch in SVN?

Tags: svn

If I rename a SVN branch with:

```
$ svn move https://server/repos/myrepo/branches/oldbranch \
    https://server/repos/myrepo/branches/newbranch
```

And then I create a new branch with same name of old branch:

```
$ svn copy <source> https://server/repos/myrepo/branches/oldbranch
```

Do I mess with SVN repository history or is it an acceptable operation?

Comment: This is an acceptable operation.

Comment: @bahrep Thank you for your help. Could you provide some explanation regarding SVN architecture/operation so I could better understand why this works?